# My phone is not moving, but GPS data still changing

Tags: android, gps

I have a simple android code to send GPS location to a database periodically via a web service. For testing purpose I set the minTime to 2000ms.

```
lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
ll=new SpeedoActionListener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000, 0,ll);
```

But...

1. when my phone is not moving, still it inserts different longitude and latitude values to the database.
2. Even I disabled GPS it sends different longitude latitude to the database untill I close the connection between my phone and the laptop.

Web service is hosted on IIS7 and my phone and laptop connected via wi-fi

Though my phone is not moving, why it sends different locations?

```
private class SpeedoActionListener implements LocationListener
{

    String result=null;

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

          if(location!=null) {
            lati=location.getLatitude();

            longi=location.getLongitude();

            String mylati=Double.toString(lati);
            String mylongi=Double.toString(longi);
            WebServiceCaller obj=new WebServiceCaller();
            result=obj.sendLocationData(mylongi, mylati);
            resultText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
            resultText.setText(result);


      }

}

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
}
}
```

Comment: May be you have some bug in code, which is sending data to web-service? Can you post it's code here?

Comment: Satellites move. Interpretation of your phone's location is based on a 'best guess' as a result of the position of multiple satellites. Also Ted Hopp's comment about using non-GPS is relevant based on availability of phone providers' networks.

Comment: I added the rest of the code,,,

Comment: @Randi Any Solution for the issue? I am stuck with similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

In low accuracy settings, data will receive from Wifi networks. Check Setting/Location/Use Wireless networks check box on your android phone.

Answer (score 4):

Android uses GPS when available, but does not rely only on GPS. The internals for when it uses what data sources is a complex subject, as described in the guide topic [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html). The location changes may come, for instance, from the phone switching strategies to save battery life.

Comment: i have tried to check the distance between the two location in onlocationchanged event. if the value of distance is more than 30 metres i ignored it. but somehow i get the distances like 400.3 , 500.7 even if the device is STILL. What can i do in this situation

Answer (score 2):

GPS has inherent imprecision, so I would expect slight variations.  I don't know why it would keep changing when you turn of GPS, though (as noted by the other answers, it's probably using an alternate source like WiFi triangulation).