# GPS location change but device not moving

Tags: android, gps

i want to know that if this is normal behavior when phone is not moving but GPS location data is changing? Difference is between 2m to 900m.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My phone is not moving, but GPS data still changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858788/my-phone-is-not-moving-but-gps-data-still-changing)

Comment: Your phone might not move, but satellites are moving, and the signal coverage varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three methods for getting location:

```
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER
```

When you ask for location by getLastKnownLocation, location provider use the best provider to get the location data. This might change according to your criteria so location data could change.

`criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);`

This setting will make your location more accurate.

Comment: Passive provider? Whats that?

Comment: That's the last known location. Even if you close your location service and 3g/wifi, if passive_provider is selected, location service returns you the last known location.

Answer (score 0):

GPS has inherent imprecision, so I would expect slight variations. I don't know why it would keep changing when you turn of GPS, though as noted by the other answers, it's probably using an alternate source like WiFi triangulation.

[My phone is not moving, but GPS data still changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858788/my-phone-is-not-moving-but-gps-data-still-changing)